# How to write code on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, code-formatting, editor

As I am having issues writing it, how do I put the code in here?

I have tried it writing like
`public function __construct() {
    $this->paginate_limit = Config::get('constants.paginate_limit');
  }`

But it doesn't work for me. Is there another way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Put the start of the code on a new line. Code blocks can be defined with the curly brackets button in the editor `{}`, or by indenting with 4 spaces.

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->paginate_limit = Config::get('constants.paginate_limit');
}
```

Similarly, in-line code can be highlighted by surrounding with the backtick " ` ".