# Can't submit question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, asking-questions

I've recently written a question for Stack Overflow. However, there isn't any submit button after I click to review my post:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I'm on a 2021 [iMac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac) using Safari if that's relevant.

Comment: Do you face this issue with other Stack Excgange sites? Do you notice any error when you click on the 'Review your question' button?

Comment: @RandomPerson-onstrike No, I routinely use mathoverflow with no issue and the 'review question' button existed at the bottom of the page as usual when I was done writing my question, but when I clicked 'review question' the page seemed to 'glitch' for a second with the only result being that the 'review question' button vanished as you see in the photo above. I have already tried discarding the draft and re-typing it, with the same end result.

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: See also: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/294055)

Comment: Please also note, that a "How to make this faster?" question might not fly on SO if you don't specify how much faster it should be.

Comment: @honk Hahah, I'm very familiar with potentially hostile posting environments -- mathoverflow is regarded as king of hostility by many. Hopefully the community at SO is a good one that will help guide me to 'culturally acceptable' post content, and if the community is unpleasant and unhelpful there are other resources available.

Comment: I don't think it's hostile. To me it makes sense. Consider you get 5 answers and you comment on all of them "that's still to slow". That would be a waste of time for you and the 5 contributors. By giving your exact requirements, other users can help you best.

Comment: @honk I assumed it was clear form context that 'faster' just meant 'doesn't give me a stackoverflow error for 4 tetrated to the power of 4', but the part of the post where I mention that implicit benchmark is cut off at the top of the page.

Comment: Code optimalisation questions like that are just not on-topic on Stack Overflow. You need to show what you tried. You need to _provide_ some benchmarks.

Also, you'll need to use block formatting instead of inline code (`\`\`\``)

Comment: @Cerbrus If you're a sample of what high-rep users are like on site, perhaps your site being buggy is a blessing in disguise lol. In any event, this is all tangential to my question -- let's please try to stay on topic here.

Comment: Well excuse me for giving you some advice on how to improve your question.

Comment: @AlecRhea Stack overflow errors are not caused by slow code. This is fundamentally different problem.

Comment: Do you have any browser plugins that might be hiding elements? (adblockers, styles, userscripts) There's no logic that _hides_ the submit button in SE itself.

Comment: @Cerbrus No, I'm mostly technologically inept (as you can tell) and am running regular old safari to my knowledge. If there are any screenshots I can provide please let me know.

Comment: Did you try a different browser? Safari is notoriously... broken.

Comment: @Cerbrus I haven't, but was trying to avoid dealing with that -- if no solutions are forthcoming I'll switch over to firefox, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can try to copy the question as is to temporary file in your computer, then reload the "Ask question" page, check again. As an variant, I can suggest try in other browsers.

Comment: You have two problems. First one is that you cannot submit your question. You have given some suggestions on how to solve that (unless it is a bug, for which community cannot help you) That first problem saved you from posting extremely poor question on Stack Overflow. Just because you haven't encountered that second problem yet, does not mean we cannot warn you about it.

Comment: @PetLinux This was the first thing I tried, but I appreciate the input -- it's looking like maybe just using another browser is the way to go.

Comment: It is not a small thing, your question asks how to make this code run faster, when in comments here you said that code causes stack overflow. This is completely different issue from the one you ask in your questions and very important piece of information you haven't written in your question. You should include all relevant information about your problem in the question. I though that my comment is self explanatory, sorry about that.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I did mention this in the body of the post, and I told honk as much in the 8th comment in this thread, but I'll repeat it again here for you.

Comment: I missed that part of the comment (comments are a bit too small for me, so I was focusing more on the image you posted than the comment) I also haven't noticed that you are using question wizard that splits question into several parts and for me it looked like this is the whole question. I would still suggest that you remove the speed part, because it is not relevant to your issue and makes your question unfocused (asking about multiple problems at once) Solution for stack overflow error will most likely solve that part, if you get answer from an expert.

Comment: @AlecRhea comments are temporary. If it's just "thanks", then it's basically noise (good intentions aside), and is liable to be removed. Don't take that personally :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus Ah, we've [discussed this at length](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5619/revisiting-our-policies-on-thank-you-comments) over at MO and decided that thanking people for their effort is a good thing qualifying as more than 'noise', even though it doesn't move things forward mathematically. (if you guys feel differently I'm fine doing away with the pleases and thank you's while here)

Comment: Yea, different sire, different rules. (Not confusing at all, I know)

Comment: @Cerbrus Business it is! I appreciate your patience putting up with me, and apologize for snapping earlier -- ironic for me to write that second sentence in light of the first, but I promise it's the last gasp of an old habit dying hard.

Comment: What version of Safari are you using? [so] [supports the last two stable versions](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/) only.

Comment: From the screencap: "Apologies, after some light searching I still can't seem to find an explanation for how to get line breaks in displayed code." There are two things wrong with this: first, commentary like this does not belong in questions, because this is **not a discussion forum**; if you are having issues with the site itself, don't include that in your post - use the comments, use Meta, whatever.

Comment: Second, this is clearly explained in the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and I can easily find this by putting something as obvious as "how to format code with line breaks on stack overflow" [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+format+code+with+line+breaks+on+stack+overflow) - after skipping the actual programming questions, I end up at [a duplicate of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373393) the [complete guide to this on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: (Incidentally, the [main "help center" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) - accessible from the top-right menu; see the circled inverted question mark? - includes a [section about asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).)

Comment: It's not simply a "cultural" difference; it's a difference in the **fundamental goal of the site**. The purpose here is to build a searchable Q&A library, and **not** to operate a service where individuals can come for customized help with idiosyncratic issues.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I find it ironic that MO is doing a better job of creating an easily searchable Q&A site than SO is, if what you say is true lol.

Comment: MO as in MathOverflow? or... because SO's being constantly abused by people using it as a help desk, degrading it's value as a knowledgebase. Lower traffic sites don't have as big of an issue with this because the tools work better on a smaller scale than they do on SO's scale.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, MathOverflow -- we get plenty of 'help desk' style questions as well, but assuming you have a site culture that engenders approximately the same percentages of productive and unproductive members as the site scales up community moderation should handle the issues you mention, and indeed at MO almost all moderation is done by community members. I suspect that SO suffers from cultural deficiencies that lead to the issues you mention, engendering a community of mostly layabouts instead of contributing members.

Comment: eh, no, quite the opposite actually. we have an active core of curators who can't possibly hope to ever be able to handle the number of things that need to be handled, because there's conceptually 1 of us and 200k of them with no tooling to support the discrepancy or promote users joining the cause rather than making it worse.

Comment: @KevinB All of which is, I suspect, a result of long-term cultural deficiencies on the site (and intense monetization).

Comment: it's 100% lack of tooling, which yes is related to monetization and lack of prioritization of the problem by the company.

Comment: @KevinB This is getting time consuming and I'd like to get back to my day, but if you had a community that actively participated to get over 3k rep to close etc. they would handle much of the burden currently placed on your 'core of curators', as is the case at MO.  We have wonderful curators, but they have busy lives and we all understand that by participating in the review queues and monitoring site activity ourselves we can make their job easier.

Comment: "I find it ironic that MO is doing a better job of creating an easily searchable Q&A site than SO is, if what you say is true lol." There's certainly nothing *surprising* about it. Stack Overflow's volume is much larger than that of any other site on the network, and the subject matter naturally attracts people who are seeking lazy homework help - programming education is even worse than math education, and programming questions have more innate potential to be embarrassingly bad, because if you write down an equation with a sign error, the paper won't spit out an error message.

Comment: Meanwhile, our site is about *15 times* the size of yours, but we have only 27 diamond moderators to your seven. Finally, there's the part where Stack Overflow is the site that the rest of the world knows about (lots of people have no idea there are other Stack Exchange sites at all, but hardly anyone who uses MO would somehow not have heard of SO), and complain about (because they think it should be a discussion forum just because there is a user content submission form). People specifically come here *just to troll about their disapproval of the ChatGPT policy*, for example.

Comment: imagine if we had 105 moderators

Comment: @KarlKnechtel We have 2-3 moderators that are active on-site, so the comparison is closer to 'imagine if we had 30-45 moderators', which... you basically do, if we round generously. But this has gotten boring; have a good day Karl.

Comment: Already wasted 2 hours trying to ask a question on `stackoverflow` and `ai.stackexchange`. No `submit` button but `review your question`. This is a serious problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the Ask Question Wizard. The next available action does not appear unless you have the previous info box in focus, and they apparently need to be filled out in order. I have never used this Wizard before and also got lost trying to figure out how to navigate between sections properly.

A simple solution is to turn off the wizard using the slider at the top of the page.

P.S. Please review the feedback provided by other users with respect to including information in your question. It will not be well-received as-is.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback! The 'feedback' I've received from the community at large here has convinced me it's no place I'd like to spend my time, but having this here for posterity is nice.

Comment: Incidentally, I didn't know this wizard existed before he/she was pointed out to me here and have never used them on any of the other stackexchange sites I visit -- I don't know if they're supposed to be casting as a default or it's a safari related bug etc., but thought this worth mentioning.